# Batch insert products (import multiple products at once)

Tags: product, database, mysql, csv, save

I have an excel file with **125.125 rows** in it. I loop through all the rows and save/update the products in my magento website.

Now the problem is that I save the product every time I loop through a row. Is there a way to save all the products at once (or 500 in one time)? Or is this bad practice?

So I don't have to make a database call for every row ... .

My excel file header looks like this:

```
ArtID || ArtNamePharmLang || ArtNameFr || ArtNameNl || PubPrice || PercentageRebate || RebateAmount || SellingPrice || Localisation || CnkNr || EanNr || SoldQty || MinThd || MaxThd || QtyInStock || DateLastSale || VatRate || SupplierManufName || BuyPrice || InvCatCode || ArtType || ApbCatCode || ApbLegCode || PharmApbNr
```

The code to import the products from the excel file looks like this:

```
if(($handle=fopen($csvFile,'r'))!==FALSE)
{
    // Default seperator is ',' -- This is changed
    while(($data=fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';'))!==FALSE)
    {
        if($row == 1){ $row++; continue; } // Don't loop through first row

        $num = count($data);
        Mage::log($num .' fields in line: ' . $row, null, self::$logFile);

        $this->importProducts($data);

        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

public function importProducts($products)
{
    // Get default store //
    $default_store = Mage::getStoreConfig('corilussync/settings/default_store'); 

    // Get specific store view //
    $dutch_store   = Mage::getStoreConfig('corilussync/settings/nl_store');
    $french_store  = Mage::getStoreConfig('corilussync/settings/fr_store');

    // Get product information //
    $sku                = $products[9];     // CnkNr
    $name_fr            = $products[2];     // ArtNameFr
    $name_nl            = $products[3];     // ArtNameNl

    $price              = $products[4];     // PubPrice     @todo: PubPrice or BuyPrice?
    $tax                = $products[16];    // VatRate
    $manufacturer       = $products[17];    // SupplierManufName
    $category           = $products[21];
    $prescript          = 0;
    $description        = $products[1];     // ArtNamePharmLang
    $date               = $products[15];    // DateLastSale

    // Allow html entities in product name //
    $name_nl = html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode(strip_tags($name_nl))));
    $name_fr = html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode(strip_tags($name_fr))));

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    // load product
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

    // if product doesn't exist, create new
    if(!is_object($product) || !$product->getId()){
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $newproduct = true;
        $newproducts++;

        Mage::log('Product with CNK '. $sku .' is a new product.',null,self::$logFile);
    }
    else{
        $updatedproducts++;

        Mage::log('Product with CNK '. $product->getSku() .' is an existing product.',null,self::$logFile);
    }

    $product->setStoreId(0)
            ->setPrice($price)
            ->setTaxClassId((int)$this->taxClass($tax))
            ->setSku($this->checkCNK($sku))
            ->setName($name_nl)
            ->setUrlKey('')
            ->setDescription($description)
            ->setShortDescription($description)
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
            ->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) // https://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type.html
            ->setAttributeSetId(4)
            ->setWeight(0)
            ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->setPrescript(0)
            ->setManufacturer($manufacturer)
            ->setCorilusUpdateDate($date)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

    try {
        $product->save();
        Mage::log('Imported product with cnk '. $sku .' in store '. $default_store, null, self::$logFile);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        Mage::log('Product with cnk '. $sku .' can\'t be imported. '. $e->getMessage(),null,self::$logFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you send your excel file header?

Comment: @Abdul, updated my topic with excel header.

Comment: have you know products Import /export in magento admin site?

Comment: @Abdul, I've updated my topic again.

Comment: Okay now clear your question and i will send bulk products import code

Comment: @Abdul, I've cleared my question.

Comment: @Abdul, is it possible to send the bulk products import code?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: @Abdul, can you post as an answer?

Comment: Oh sorry. I will gv